# Determine how many times change device, SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have the following table and I would like to create new variables from it.
I want know, 'On average, how often do you change devices by month?'.
This the table_1 in SQL, AWS Athenas

```
       id    date     month device      carrier
12-ac8147   2019       4    Sgx1         alca
12-ac8147   2019       5    Sgx1         alca
12-ac8147   2019       5    Sgx1         alca
12-ac8147   2019       6    Sgx1         alca
12-ac8147   2019       6    Sgx1         alca
12-ac8147   2019       6    iPhone8,1    telc
12-ac8147   2019       9    iPhone8,1    telc
12-ac8147   2019       9    iPhone8,1    telc
12-ac8147   2020       1    iPhone8,1    telc
12-ac8147   2020       10   iPhone11,2   telc
12-ac8147   2020       12   iPhone11,2   telc
12-ac8147   2020       12   iPhone11,2   service_m
12-ac8147   2020       12   iPhone11,2   service_m
12-ac8147   2020       12   iPhone11,2   service_m
12-ac8147   2021       1    iPhone11,2   service_m
12-ac8147   2021       12   iPhone11,5   service_m
12-ac8147   2021       12   iPhone11,5   movil_tel
```

So my idea was, (in sql athenas aws amazon)

```
with table as(
id, device, max(year*100+month) mas_n, min(year*100+month) min_n)
FROM table_1
where device is not null and device <>''
group by id, device
)

SELECT id, avg(max_n-min_n) prom_dif
FROM table
GROUP BY id
```

But this doesn't work, 'cause count all the months.

```
    id              prom_dif
12-ac8147            206
```

Comment: Please Edit your question to also show the Output you would want from your query, for the input data you have shown.

Answer (score 0):

```
;with datas as(
select '12-ac8147' id,'2019-03-29' date,'Sgx1' device,'alca' carrier
union select '12-ac8147','2019-04-04','Sgx1','alca'
union select '12-ac8147','2019-05-01','Sgx1','alca'
union select '12-ac8147','2019-05-13','Sgx1','alca'
union select '12-ac8147','2019-05-18','Sgx1','alca'
union select '12-ac8147','2019-05-19','iPhone8,1','telc'
union select '12-ac8147','2019-08-09','iPhone8,1','telc'
union select '12-ac8147','2019-08-16','iPhone8,1','telc'
union select '12-ac8147','2019-12-30','iPhone8,1','telc'
union select '12-ac8147','2020-09-24','iPhone11,2','telc'
union select '12-ac8147','2020-11-11','iPhone11,2','telc'
union select '12-ac8147','2020-11-17','iPhone11,2','service_m'
union select '12-ac8147','2020-11-19','iPhone11,2','service_m'
union select '12-ac8147','2020-11-25','iPhone11,2','service_m'
union select '12-ac8147','2020-12-03','iPhone11,2','service_m'
union select '12-ac8147','2021-12-03','iPhone11,5','service_m'
union select '12-ac8147','2021-12-17','iPhone11,5','movil_tel'   
),cte2 as(
select id,count(distinct device) no_of_device_changed,count(distinct carrier) no_of_carrier_changed from datas group by id)
,cte3 as(
select *,lag(carrier)over(partition by id order by date) prev_carrier from datas)
,cte4 as(
select * from cte3 where carrier <> coalesce(prev_carrier,'')
),cte5 as(
select *,lag(date) over(partition by id order by date) as prev_carrier_dt from cte4)
,cte6 as (select id,avg(date_diff('day',prev_carrier_dt,date)) avg_dt from cte5 group by id)
select a.id,a.avg_dt as avg_carrier_change,b.no_of_carrier_changed,b.no_of_device_changed from cte6 a
join cte2 b on a.id = b.id
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I did the same query. How could I see how often does it change carrier?

Comment: what is the logic for often, do you need the average days?

Comment: I am inventing variables, I think that for number of days, it could be a good idea

Comment: Also, does it occur to you that another new variable could be created from this data?. Thank!

Comment: I don't get it @PetherCll_,another new variable?

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, but I am using SQL athenas AWS Amazon, and when I try to use your query it does not work for me

Comment: are you getting any error? or the result you expect is different

Comment: I edit my question. I get an error with funciton isnull. Thanks again!

Comment: I have updated the code, check now

Comment: Thanks! but the query say 'Column 'day' cannot be resolved', thanks a lot!

Comment: change the function to date_diff('day',